# Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I am trying deploy my rails application on heroku. I used the command

> heroku run rake db:migrate

and I am getting the following error

> Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2846  !
>   Heroku client internal error.  !    Search for help at:
>   https://help.heroku.com  !    Or report a bug at:
>   https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
>
> ```
> Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
> ```

I tried the same command yesterday it worked perfectly.

Comment: Try again. Your connection timed out. Are you doing anything unusual like connecting from a flaky network? You can also check the [heroku status page](https://status.heroku.com/) when things like this happen, but I don't see any current issues up there right now.

Comment: Actually, I guess there was an issue that was resolved a few minutes ago that may or may not have been related.

Comment: i tried many times and I am using my school network to deploy my application.. ll try again..

Comment: If it doesn't go away you may consider contacting support.

Comment: i still have the same error.. ll contact the support ..

Comment: looks like my University ll not allow to use 5000 port. So i cannot able to deploy from my University network. Problem solved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://www.orhancanceylan.com/heroku-run-command-operation-timed-out/
You internet provider is blocking port:5000, but you can still deploy.

```
heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
```

Comment: same link also talks about "provider blocking a port". Had similar issue with VPN provider. I've just connected to different VPN location (Ireland as Heroku server is in Ireland) and it worked with plain `heroku run bash`