# CSV Parse Taking Too Much Memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord, activerecord-import

I'm trying to read a 5MM line file and right now it is exceeding my alotted memory usage on heroku. My method is somewhat fast ~200 inserts/second.. I believe it's crashing on the import.. So my plan was to import in batches of 1,000 or 10,000. My question is how do I tell that I'm at the end of my file, ruby has a `.eof` method but its a `File` method, and I'm not sure how to call it in my loop

```
    def self.import_parts_db(file)
        time = Benchmark.measure do
            Part.transaction do 
                parts_db = []
                CSV.parse(File.read(file), headers: true) do |row|
                    row_hash = row.to_hash
                    part = Part.new(
                        part_num: row_hash["part_num"], 
                        description: row_hash["description"], 
                        manufacturer: row_hash["manufacturer"],
                        model: row_hash["model"],
                        cage_code: row_hash["cage_code"],
                        nsn: row_hash["nsn"]
                        )
                    parts_db << part
                end
                Part.import parts_db
            end
        end
        puts time
    end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 1st problem

As soon as you use `File.read(file)` with a huge file, your script will use a lot of memory (possibly too much). You read the entire file into 1 huge string, even though `CSV` reads it line by line.

It might work fine when you use files with thousands of rows. Still, you should use [CSV.foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach).
Change

```
 CSV.parse(File.read(file), headers: true) do |row|
```

to

```
CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
```

In [this](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/68-processing-large-csv-files-with-ruby) example, memory usage went from 1GB to 0.5MB.

## 2nd problem

`parts_db` becomes a huge Array of Parts, which keeps growing until the very end of the CSV file.
You need to either remove the transaction (import will be slow but won't require more memory than for 1 row) or process the CSV in batches.

Here's one possibility to do it. We use `CSV.parse` again, but only with batches of 2000 lines :

```
def self.import_parts_db(filename)
  time = Benchmark.measure do
    File.open(filename) do |file|
      headers = file.first
      file.lazy.each_slice(2000) do |lines|
        Part.transaction do
          rows = CSV.parse(lines.join, write_headers: true, headers: headers)
          parts_db = rows.map do |_row|
            Part.new(
              part_num: row_hash['part_num'],
              description: row_hash['description'],
              manufacturer: row_hash['manufacturer'],
              model: row_hash['model'],
              cage_code: row_hash['cage_code'],
              nsn: row_hash['nsn']
            )
          end
          Part.import parts_db
        end
      end
    end
    puts time
  end
end
```

## 3rd problem?

The previous answer shouldn't use much memory, but it still could take a long time to import everything, possibly too much for a remote server.

The advantage of using an Enumerator is that it's easy to skip batches, and get just the ones you want.

Let's say your import takes too long, and stops for some reason after 424000 successful imports.

You could replace :

```
file.lazy.each_slice(2000) do |lines|
```

by

```
file.lazy.drop(424_000).take(300_000).each_slice(2000) do |lines|
```

To skip the first 424000 CSV lines, and parse the next 300000 ones.

For the next import, use :

```
file.lazy.drop(424_000+300_000).take(300_000).each_slice(2000) do |lines|
```

and then :

```
file.lazy.drop(424_000+2*300_000).take(300_000).each_slice(2000) do |lines|
```

...

Comment: But above you recommended `.foreach`.. would it not work in this instance?

Comment: `CSV.foreach` doesn't return an Enumerable, which is what we need for `each_slice`. As long as you don't use `File.read()`, it's okay to use `CSV.parse`. In the 2nd case, it's only for 2000 lines.

Comment: I used your example and I got an `ETIMEDOUT: read ETIMEDOUT` error from the heroku console after 424,000 Imports. Do you know how I can get around that?

Comment: I have no experience with Heroku. Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992689/operation-timed-out-connect2-errnoetimedout?

Comment: I saw that, but I don't think that's it. I think it was the time it was taking to complete the task. Thanks though, you've been great help!

Answer (score 0):

`CSV.parse` is pretty efficient, passing one parsed CSV line to the block that does the processing.
The problem doesn't come from the CSV parser, it comes from building the `parts_db` array in memory. I suggest rewriting the `Part.import` method to import the data line by line, instead of an entire array of records at once.

Answer (score -3):

Try a different CSV.  Had one that was about 30 megs that used 8 remaining gigs of RAM, resaving the file seemed to have corrected my issue.